# Override the active profile using OS Environment variable?

Tags: spring-boot

I have a dockerfile that creates an image that starts a Spring Boot application with `-Dspring_profiles_active=test` on the command line. Now I want to be able to override the profile based on the environment. I had thought that passing an environment variable like `-e SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev` when starting the container would override the command line setting, but it does nothing. If I pass  `-e spring_profiles_active=dev` I get both as shown in the Spring Boot logs: `... : The following profiles are active: dev,test`, not what I wanted.

1. Why doesn't the uppercase version do anything, and
2. Why does the lowercase version "include" rather than replace?

I thought the precedence order was OS environment variable, then command line (i.e. -D) then application.properites, as per the documentation: [Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)

EDIT: Corrected typo above. Also, I'm using `Spring Boot v1.5.9.RELEASE, Spring v4.3.13.RELEASE` and if I remove the `-Dspring_profiles_active=test` command line options the OS environment variable then passes into the application as expected.

Cheers,
Matt

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
-e SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev
```

Instead of

```
-e SPRING_PROFILE_ACTIVE=dev
```

It is `PROFILES`

Comment: That was a cut & paste error in my post, you can see from the other examples I'm using the plural version - PROFILES

Comment: I will go back and make sure.

Comment: Definitely used/using  SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE, it was just a typo in the post.